# Use fetch method inside vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a store action that fetch api. When I'm trying to dispatch it from component in created lifecycle hook. I'm getting Cannot `read property 'dispatch' of undefined` error. I know there are several similar questions but none of them solved this issue.

I tried to dispatch it also in normal method and still get this error.

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "Vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_CATEGORIES(state, categories) {
      state.categories = categories;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getCategories({ commit }) {
      return fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories")
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(jsonObj => {
          commit("SET_CATEGORIES", jsonObj);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the component which I try to dispatch in -

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      joke: "",
      categories: [],
      selectedCat: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    disabled() {
      if (this.joke) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToFavs: function() {
      this.$emit("pushJoke", this.joke);
      this.fetchJoke();
    }

  },

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getCategories');
  }  
};
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` tells you, that the problem is not with fetch, but with your store. Vue component is unable to find this action in the store and it will be the same event without the fetch.

Comment: Thanks, any reason why based on my code?

Comment: @KingGary that's not right. It's not that it can't find the action, it can't find the store at all. - OP, please post wherever you're initializing your Vue object (`new Vue({...})`) - this is more likely to be the source of the issue.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't add the `store` to the Vue instance. Something like this:  `const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  ...
})`

Comment: @KingGary you're right, I added it now and the error disappeared but fetch is not working, so probably now the problem it's with the action itself.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
```

in your script

then add to `methods`

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
     'getCategories'
  ])
.
.
}
```

and alter your created method to

```
created() {
  this.getCategories()
}
```

Furthermore, you might want to create a vuex action to replace that `this.$emit("pushJoke", this.joke);` line that you have, and map that in a similar way that you have mapped `getCategories`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you missed to add your vuex store option to the root instance of Vue. To solve that import your store and attach it to your vue instance.

```
import { store } from '.store'

const app = new Vue({
  store
})
```